# An identity about Bessel functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, special-functions, bessel-functions

How can I  prove

$\frac { 2n}{\rho}J_n (\rho)=J_{n-1}(\rho)+J_{n+1}(\rho)$

?

When $J_n$ is n'th order Bessel function.

I tried a lot, but I don't know how to construct  $"n"$ in the LHS.

Is there any hint?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Bessel functions appear in a particular [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Properties) :
$$ \exp\left(\frac{\rho}{2}\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} J_n(\rho)\,t^n. \tag{1}$$
By differentiating both sides of the previous identity with respect to $t$ we get:
$$ \frac{\rho}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\exp\left(\frac{\rho}{2}\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)\right) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} J_n(\rho)\, n t^{n-1}\tag{2} $$
hence:
$$ \frac{\rho}{2}\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}J_n(\rho)\, t^n = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} J_n(\rho)\, n t^n\tag{3} $$
and by equating the coefficients of $t^n$ in the LHS and RHS of $(3)$ your identity follows.